# Java Socket Server with HTML form File Upload

Tags: java, html, forms, sockets, upload

I'm trying too make a Java html server that allows users too upload files. I do not wish too use tomcat or any other library. I already have my code working too allow browsers too connect too it. However I can't seem too figure out how too get a file uploaded from a html form.

```
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println("<html>NEXT PAGE</html>");
                System.out.println(response);

                response = readLine(socket);
                System.out.println(response);

                receiveFile(new File("/home/user/Downloads/blla.html"));

//THE FUNCTIONS

public String readLine(Socket socket)throws IOException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine, builder = "";
    while(!(inputLine = in.readLine()).equals("")){
        builder += inputLine+"\r\n";
    }

    return builder+"\r\n";
}

public void receiveFile(File file){
    try{
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my html form for uploading the file.

```
        <form action='/u' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select image to upload:
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>
```

- UPDATE -
  I realized that the BufferedReader is buffering some of the output of the POST content. So I'm now just using an inputstream and reading the content and then adding the POST part too the file. However now the file seems too be about 3KB too big, I also was able too parse the last bit of the POST which contained an end of packet bit.

Comment: If you are not using"TomCat" (I use Google to host my pages) I would like to hear how you are making a web browser connect to your Java Classes (the one with the sockets)?  It sounds interesting.  Just out of curiosity - is your web-browser actually making a connection to some JVM, or just showing you your HTML page on your hard-drive?

Comment: Well, I would, but I'm making a custom http/https proxy that allows users too have custom websites within it. However too do so I need too allow the user too upload an html file. In other words this is a java Web server not a client. The browser, like chrome or firefox are the client.

Comment: Well, that sounds like more work than you have "portrayed" by the wording in the question.  I mean, I use Google Cloud Server to host a website, and my pages do not have any java or script at all.  I host "Foreign News Translation" sites - and long story short, I have thousands of lines of Java that do work offline, but online - I only have static HTML pages.  But this is supposed to be about your question, not mine....  How are you going to "serve" pages to end users?  Don't you need somekind of web-server?  It's not going to be hosted on your computer at home, is it?  Do you have an office?

Comment: I mean there is: Google Cloud Server, Microsoft Azure.   I started with 1&1.com for hosting pages.  If you want a Server that has a web-page that lets users upload files that are then turned into web-pages themselves....  That sounds basically easy, but (for me) the **hard part is getting to a point where you have a functioning web-server** on the internet, first.  Once you have that - then receiving a file from an HTML form post is basically trivial - I could post an answer for that.  Saving it to the file-system is also easy...  **I mean** I could do this with Google Cloud Server right now..

Comment: I understand your concern for the hosting method. It will be hosted on a private server in the denver tech center once complete. Therefore a java proxy server allowing users too upload files will not be an issue. I have gotten my proxy too override certain domain extensions with new ones and allowed override with gets. However post via form data wont work.

Comment: Well, I should not be answering question anyway.  I use Java to post files (usually Java source files) to web-servers every day, but I have not written HTML `<FORM>` posts in ages...  Sorry, your question sounded like what I was doing all day... But not... I guess.

Comment: No worries haha, I do that kinda thing all the time as well. However parsing as a server beats me haha.

Comment: HEY!  You still there?  I don't really ever use the Apache Commons jar-files, but that isn't for any particularly good reason.  I was just reading the String Routines, and I saw this jar-library for [file uploading with Servlets](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)...  Note, I don't know the first thing about it...  Other than that people on SO cite Apache Utilities pretty often.

Comment: I did get it solved. But thank you for the idea, Im looking into the Apache commons now.